# Mechanical design of a bioreactor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, systems-design, machine-design, biogas

What books and online materials exist that explain the mechanical design of a bioreactor? Can someone recommend any?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=mechanical+design+bioreactor

Answer (score 1):

Bioreactors: Process and Analysis, by Tapobrata Panda

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HVGSfMa062kC

[image: Bioreactors Book Cover]

"This book also covers the mechanical design considerations for the various kinds of bioreactors."

Comment: Do you know a website I can download it from or read it online for free?

Comment: I do not, sorry. That lies outside the scope of your original question, and of this Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You may wish to look for a local library with a subscription to the McGraw-Hill AccessEngineering Catalogue: https://www.accessengineeringlibrary.com/content/book/9780070704244/chapter/chapter12

Comment: Or, you can use this: https://www.worldcat.org/title/bioreactors-analysis-and-design/oclc/907907002#borrow to find a hardcopy in major libraries that are helpful enough to upload ther information. Without knowing where you are there's nothing I can do to help...

Comment: Thanks! I am grateful. Do you know any other online resource or eBook that can be useful?

Comment: No - I mainly posted this answer as an example of just how easy it is to find this information yourself using google... (see my comment on your question)